# Is a punctuation error in a list a critical mistake on a CV?

Tags: resume, hiring-process

I basically was listing things like this:

> item 1, item 2, etc

and I used a period instead of a comma:

> item 1, item2. etc

Is this considered an important error?

Comment: I really doubt anyone will even notice. Note that "etc" is an abbreviation which needs its own dot at the end.

Comment: Only if you claim to be detail-oriented. ;)

Comment: And when used like that it is called a period not a dot.

Comment: Define "important"...

Comment: I notice them. I usually treat it as a minor demerit ("you had one job") but won't nix the candidate out of hand.

Comment: Was this the only error, or was it one out of several?  This particular error may not be important itself, but if the errors accumulate to give a sloppy impression, then that may indeed be a negative.

Comment: In the UK, it's called a full stop, @HLGEM.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - Here in the U.S., no one has any idea what a full stop is at all, but that's just our driving.  (Ba-dum tiss)

Comment: Ask yourself, do you really want to work for someone who would bin your cv for this? I'd correct it before you print it again, but dont sweat over it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> is it considered an important error?

No, unless you're applying for a proofreading position or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. Unless the job is for writing perfectly formed CVs for people.
Focus on attitude first and foremost, then skills. 
That level of punctuation pedantry is rarely needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not.  I once had a interviewer point out a typo in my resume and got an offer anyway.  Your resume should look professional, but a single errant period probably doesn't matter.